# Make Highcharts pick a smart y-axis min

Tags: charts, highcharts, statistics

For a bar or column chart in Highcharts, is there a setting(s) to make it automatically set the min of the y-axis based on the min of the data?  For example, if my data values fall between 200 and 300, then the plot doesn't look so good if the chart y-axis starts at 0, but rather it looks much better if the y-axis min is 200.

My current approach is supply the yAxis.min setting the minimum vale from the data subtracted by some "smart offset" (smart offset so that the min of the data is not plotted at the very bottom).  The problem is i'm not 100% yet how to calculate that "smart offset" so I'm wondering if Higcharts can do the min from the data for me (rather than supplying it), then it might be able also figure out that offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `softThreshold` property:

> **softThreshold: boolean**
>
> When this is true, the series will not cause the Y axis to cross the
>   zero plane (or threshold option) unless the data actually crosses the
>   plane. (...)

```
series: [{
    softThreshold: true,
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/05tgmz9c/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.softThreshold